# Smallest circumcircle around four non-overlapping unit semicircles

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

What is the radius of the smallest circle into which will fit four unit half-disks? What arrangement of the half-disks achieves this? How is it proved optimal?

The best arrangement I've found fits in a circle of radius $\frac1{30}(50-5\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{55})$: 
[image: Upper bound arrangement]

Could this actually be optimal? I certainly haven't been able to prove it.

The best lower bound I have is the obvious $\sqrt{2}$ based on comparing areas.

Note on source: I found this question [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-smallest-circle-in-which-four-identical-semicircles-of-radius-1-can-be-fitted-inside).

Comment: Packing problems are hard.  You can visit packomania.com for examples.  It is surprising what configurations turn out to be (as far as we know) optimal

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the optimal configuration is, but yours isn't.  Consider rotating your two-half-disk circle by slightly less than $\pi/2$.  You can then slide one of the half-disks so it doesn't touch the outer circle.  And then you can adjust the outer circle to make it smaller.

EDIT: I mean that in a configuration like this

[image]

you can slide the yellow half-disk.

[image]

Oh, and by the way, I believe your large circle has radius $13/8$, not $\frac1{30}(50-5\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{55})$.

Comment: Why slightly less than pi/2 instead of exactly pi/2? Which half-disk can be slid in your arrangement?